# Select, where and then inner join two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to select the users that have above 50 points and have logged in in the past 3 months. I then want to join those users up using the ID's from both tables so i have the orders table row attached to each user the above query returns.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT  Users.EmailAddress, Users.RewardPoints, Orders.UserID, Users.ID From Users
WHERE RewardPoints > 50 AND Users.LastLoggedIn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
Inner Join Orders ON Orders.UserID = Users.ID;
```

But it gives me this error:

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Inner Join Orders
>       On Orders.UserID = Users.ID LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

---

EDIT Figured it out!

SELECT  Users.EmailAddress, Users.RewardPoints, Orders.UserID, Users.ID,
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Orders On Orders.UserID = Users.ID 
WHERE Users.RewardPoints > 50 AND  Users.LastLoggedIn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);

Comment: if you can, you should post just the structure of your tables, not the data.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that? The create table statements?

Comment: yes or a code formatted table header like this:
table user: `| ID | NAME | SURNAME |`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join table after the where condition, you should put it last (in your case).

```
SELECT  Users.EmailAddress, Users.RewardPoints, Orders.UserID, Users.ID
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN Orders On Orders.UserID = Users.ID
WHERE RewardPoints > 50 AND Users.LastLoggedIn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE RewardPoints > 50 AND Users.LastLoggedIn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONT' at line 1

Comment: post the complete structure of your tables

Comment: also, you added a tag that is "sql-server", is that mysql or mssql?

Comment: I've updated my answer, pleas try it now, it should work. There was an extra `;`

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE statement should come *after* the JOIN statement

Comment: The order is: SELECT FROM JOIN ON WHERE

Comment: well, seems a copy&paste answer is better... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Either move the WHERE after the JOINs:

```
select ...
from ...
join ...
where ...
```

Or use an inner query:

```
SELECT  Users.EmailAddress, Users.RewardPoints, Orders.UserID, Users.ID
From (select ^ from Users
  WHERE RewardPoints > 50 AND Users.LastLoggedIn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) Users
Inner Join Orders
  On Orders.UserID = Users.ID;
```